# Use same array of objects in different components and if any update to one will show the update in other component in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, components, observable

I am using two different components in a single page but in different sections. The array of objects is fetched from same service call. In one component I am using hostname and description but in second component I am showing all values of the service response

I am using contenteditable to make some changes to the data and on blur I am updating the changes in the array of objects. There is a save button at the end which is updating all the values in the database which is in on component.

The first component shows list of hosts where user can remove hosts. Removing a host will only remove it from the array of objects. So if a host is removed from the first component, I want the changes to be reflected in the second component.
Before I used rxjs store to maintain state but then it is not allowing me to make any changes to the array of objects and giving an error of field is read only.

Is there any way if I make any changes to first component array it also updates the other one.

Here's my code:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ConfirmationDialogService } from '../../../../pages/setting/confirmation-dialog/confirmation-dialog.service';

import { NotifierService } from 'angular-notifier';
import { VulnerabilityScanService } from '../../../../services/vulnerability-scan.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-vuln-scan-scanned-host',
  templateUrl: './vuln-scan-scanned-host.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vuln-scan-scanned-host.component.scss'],
})
export class VulnScanScannedHostComponent implements OnInit {

  scannedHosts: any;
  distinctHosts: any;
  filter: any;
  isDelete: any;
  private notifier: NotifierService;
  constructor(private VulnerabilityScanService: VulnerabilityScanService,
     private confirmationDialogService: ConfirmationDialogService,
     notifier: NotifierService, 
     private store: Store<any>) 
     { this.notifier = notifier;}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filter =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reportFilters'));

    this.VulnerabilityScanService.getReportDataOnHostSchedule(this.filter).subscribe(payload => {
      this.scannedHosts = payload;
        
      const key = 'ip'; 

      const arrayUniqueByKey = [...new Map(this.scannedHosts.map(item =>
      [item[key], item])).values()];

      this.isDelete = arrayUniqueByKey.length;
    });
  }
  
  removeHost(host, index){
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Delete HOST', 'Do you want to delete selected HOST?')
    .then((confirmed) => {
      if (confirmed) {
        this.removeHostEntries(host, this.scannedHosts);
        console.log(this.scannedHosts);
        
        this.showNotification('success', 'HOST successfully deleted.');
        
      } else {

      }
    });
  }

  removeHostEntries(hostip, scannedHosts) {
    scannedHosts.forEach((value,index)=>{
        if(value.ip==hostip) scannedHosts.splice(index,1);
    });
  } 

  public showNotification(type: string, message: string): void {
    this.notifier.notify(type, message);
  }
}
```

Here' the second component:

```
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { VulnerabilityScanService } from '../../../../services/vulnerability-scan.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-vuln-scan-summary',
  templateUrl: './vuln-scan-summary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./vuln-scan-summary.component.scss'],
})
export class VulnScanSummaryComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('searchInput', { static: false }) searchInput: ElementRef;
  summaryList: any;
  editedList: any;
  showAlert: false;
  selectedOrderBy: any = '0';
  selectedFilterBy: any;
  public isDetailsOpen: boolean[] = [] ;
  
  // enableEditDesc : boolean[] = [];
  // enableEditDescIndex : boolean[] = [];
  
  

  constructor(private VulnerabilityScanService: VulnerabilityScanService,private store: Store<any>) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

     this.selectedFilterBy =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reportFilters'));
     

       this.VulnerabilityScanService.getReportDataOnHostSchedule(this.selectedFilterBy).subscribe(payload => {
        this.summaryList = payload;
        console.log(this.summaryList)
      });
  }
 
  saveReport(data) {
    
    this.VulnerabilityScanService.saveReviewedReport(data).subscribe(payload => {
      console.log(payload);
    });
  }

  toggleRow(i: any) {
    this.isDetailsOpen[i] = !this.isDetailsOpen[i];
  }

  

}
```

Comment: This is a short path to an unmaintable code. The state management solutions don't allow to mutate data for a reason. One component should update the state with the latest changes and the state would be propagated to the other component as well without the need to mutate the data.

Comment: Earlier I was doing with state management but then it doesn't allow me to update the array if I make any inline edits to the page.

Comment: you should continue to use rxjs but you should use a behavior subject.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the state management I would try something like this.

Define a shared singleton service.

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ReportDataStore {
  private _data: any[];
  
  get data() {
    return this._data;
  }

  set data(d) {
    return this._data = d;
  }

}
```

Inject it in both components and set the data.

```
  this.VulnerabilityScanService.getReportDataOnHostSchedule(this.filter).subscribe(payload => {
      this.reportDataStore.data = payload;
      this.scannedHosts = this.reportDataStore.data;
        
      const key = 'ip'; 

      const arrayUniqueByKey = [...new Map(this.scannedHosts.map(item =>
      [item[key], item])).values()];

      this.isDelete = arrayUniqueByKey.length;
    });


   this.VulnerabilityScanService.getReportDataOnHostSchedule(this.selectedFilterBy).subscribe(payload => {
        this.reportDataStore.data = payload;
        this.summaryList = this.reportDataStore.data;
        console.log(this.summaryList)
      });
```

The local variables in the components should now maintain a reference to the same array in the ReportDataStore service.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got it solved using Observable and Subject. Here's the service code:

````
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class VulScanConfig {

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() { }

  sendReport(passedData: any) {
    this.subject.next(passedData);
  }

 getReport(): Observable<any> {
   return this.subject.asObservable();
 }

}```

Then in my parent component when any action is done I've called the sendReport function of data servicee. Here's the code of parent component:

```sendReport(data): void {
    this.vulScanConfig.sendReport(data);
  }
  
  removeHost(host, scheduleid, hostkey){
    this.confirmationDialogService.confirm('Delete HOST', 'Do you want to delete selected HOST?')
    .then((confirmed) => {
      if (confirmed) {        
        const assetFilterData = {
          scheduleId: scheduleid,
          hostkey:hostkey,
          host: host,
          filteredData: this.filteredHosts
        };
        this.sendReport(assetFilterData);        
      }
    });
  }```

The child component then subscribe to data by calling getReport function of data service and subscribe to message.

```import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
constructor(private VulnerabilityScanService: VulnerabilityScanService,
    private vulScanConfig: VulScanConfig, 
    private store: Store<any>) {
      this.subscription = this.vulScanConfig.getReport().subscribe(message=>  {
        if (message) {

          this.summaryList = message.filteredData;
          this.hostkey = message.hostkey;
          this.ip = message.host;
          this.scheduleId = message.scheduleId;

        } 
      });
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }```
````